# Best practices for returning multiple values?

Tags: java, performance, memory, optimization, memory-management

Let's say I want to design a function that returns information on a given stock. The function receives the stock name as a parameter of type String, then returns several values. Some values it might return are:

```
int price
int profitability
double currentTrend
int mostRecentSpike
long timeOfRecentSpike
```

As you can see they are all of different primitive types. I am wondering what the best way to return these values is from an optimization standpoint. So if I were to make a custom Object like so:

```
class Stock {
    int price;
    int profitability;
    double currentTrend;
    int mostRecentSpike;
    long timeOfRecentSpike;
    public Stock(int price, int profitability, double currentTrend, int mostRecentSpike, long timeOfRecentSpike) {
        this.price = price;
        this.profitability = profitability;
        this.currentTrend = currentTrend;
        this.mostRecentSpike = mostRecentSpike;
        this.timeOfRecentSpike = timeOfRecentSpike;
    }
}
```

and returned that, would it be better than an alternative where I simply returned this:

```
new Object[] {price, profitability, currentTrend, mostRecentSpike, timeOfRecentSpike}
```

and then casted everything into its appropriate primitive types? While I do understand that readability will be decreased when returning and casting an Object[], I'm mostly concerned with the performance in terms of CPU, memory, and serialization.

- Which would be more CPU intensive?
- Which would take up more memory?
- Which would be best paired with serialization?

This problem is just a metaphor for a much larger problem I'm actually having, just on a much larger scale that requires a lot more explanation. So even if the difference is negligible in this small example, it will scale up to be much more significant in my actual situation.

Comment: *"from an optimization standpoint"* - why? What performance problems are you facing?

Comment: CPU and memory should be about the same (arrays are objects in Java, so they're the same as your object).  A custom class is best for serialization, since you can give it a fixed serialization ID and override methods to provide custom serialization if needed.  A custom class is also better for code readability.

Comment: Return the `Stock`, so the fields retain their type and semantic meaning.

Comment: Fwiw, Google uses [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) extensively for this exact purpose.

Comment: "So even if the difference is negligible in this small example, it will scale up to be much more significant in my actual situation." The biggest problem with returning everything in an `Object[]` is that you lose semantic information. The second biggest problem is that you have to box all the primitives, which hits you with an overhead for each array element. Using a custom class allows you to store things as primitives, so you only take the overhead once per return value.

Comment: @AndyTurner would it be better to just store them in boxed format? So each int is now an Integer, long is now Long, etc?

Comment: @KaelEppcohen if you're concerned about memory usage, no. An `int` takes 4 bytes; an `Integer` 12. So you can store your 3 int fields in the space it would take to store 1 as an Integer.

Comment: @Andy `Integer` - `16` as minimum...

Comment: @Oleksandr my mistake, I was thinking of just the overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to sum up the comments into one coherent answer since those answered my question to a great deal.

**markspace:**

Since Arrays are Objects in Java, they will have similar structure to the Stock custom class, and as a result require essentially the same amount of memory and CPU resources.

The custom class has an advantage from a serialization point of view because it has a fixed serialization ID which can also be customized if desired.

The custom class also improves readability.

**Andy Turner:**

With an Object[] each value entered will become an Object, and when you retrieve elements from that Array you'll need to box them from Object to their non-primitive counterpart (Long, Double, Integer) which has some overhead. With a custom class, you'll be storing everything as a primitive, so there is no boxing required and as a result no overhead.

Also in case you were thinking of using non-primitive values inside of your custom class, it's worse from a memory perspective. Having a field be of type `int` is ~4 times more memory efficient than storing it as an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Well *from an optimization standpoint* the best practice is to return a Stock object because casting will cause much more cpu and memory usage, and even can lead to exceptions like classCastException if in any case you miss any variables.

So,

```
return new Stock(price, profitability, currentTrend, mostRecentSpike, timeOfRecentSpike);
```

Comment: The time you would spend debugging the incorrect types and array bounds errors would dwarf the extra time and memory cost.

Answer (score 0):

While you say

> it will scale up to be much more significant in my actual situation.

I suspect you've not actually got figures to prove that (as if you had, I doubt you'd be asking here...)

I'd suggest you write it in the clearest way possible, which probably involves passing a reference to the actual object around, until you've actually got figures to **prove** that it's a real problem.  (99% of the time, the 'obvious' time sink isn't)